# Grabbing Descendants from an XDocument

Tags: c#, linq-to-xml

I am trying to grab all the `<entry>` tags from [this site](http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles). It will load just fine into an XDocument but I cannot seem to grab any of the `<entry>` elements. Here is the code I have:

```
XDocument netflixPage = new XDocument();
netflixPage = XDocument.Load("http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles");

foreach (XElement xe in netflixPage.Descendants("entry").ToList())
{
    string movieInfo = xe.Value;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code attempts to retrieve `entry` elements in the   namespace, but the document contains `entry` elements in the `http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom`  namespace:

```
XNamespace atom = "http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom";

XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles");

foreach (XElement xe in doc.Descendants(atom + "entry"))
{
    string movieInfo = (string)xe;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, that worked great! Now, I am trying to grab some more information such as the <d:ReleaseYear>. I tried this code: 

XNamespace msft = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"; 
XDocument netflixPage = new XDocument(); 
netflixPage = XDocument.Load("http://odata.netflix.com/Catalog/Titles"); 
foreach (XElement xe in netflixPage.Descendants(msft + "d")) 
{ 
string stuff = xe.Value; 
} 

but it wouldn't load. Do you know how to grab the <d> elements?

Comment: @user500975: `d` is the prefix of the element, not the name. You can ignore it. The name of the element is `ReleaseYear` in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices` namespace. You can access it with `msft + "ReleaseYear"` where `XNamespace msft = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices";`